# Error after update OmniFaces 2.6

Tags: jsf-2.2, omnifaces

I'm having the following error when upgrading to the newer version of omnifaces.

I'm using javax.faces-2.2.8-19.jar, omnifaces-2.6.jar

```
SEVERE: Critical error during deployment: 
com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: 
  Source Document: jar:file:/./lib/omnifaces-2.6.jar!/META-INF/faces-config.xml
  Cause: Class 'org.omnifaces.el.FacesELResolver' is missing a runtime dependency: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.omnifaces.el.FacesELResolver (initialization failure)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.createInstance(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:364)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ApplicationConfigProcessor.addELResolver(ApplicationConfigProcessor.java:658)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're apparently using Java 1.7.

This was caused by an accidentally introduced Java 1.8 specific [`Method#getParameterCount()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getParameterCount--) call which somehow [slipped through](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/blob/2.6/src/main/java/org/omnifaces/el/FacesELResolver.java#L57) in spite of the `pom.xml` [clearly](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/blob/2.6/pom.xml#L63) telling Maven to compile the code using Java 1.7. Why Maven seemed to ignore the Java version in `pom.xml` is not clear yet as of now.

This has been acknowledged and [fixed](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/commit/f0da6b1c02f20ae32a3178249f596571aeead4ab) as per [issue 358](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/issues/358). The fix is available in [OmniFaces 2.6.1](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/omnifaces/omnifaces/2.6.1/).